# Can not run any program on windows server Azure VM with windows powershell remote, No error

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, powershell-remoting

I want to run remotely some programs on Azure windows server from a windows machine using windows powershell remote. It was configured and I can do copy, delete, add and get process and etc.. but i can not run any program such as .cmd , .txt, ... on remote Azure VM. I don't get any error.

I tried Invoke-item, Invoke-process, ... for executing. I will appreciate if you help me.

Br,

Comment: So what happens and what would you expect to happen? And how would you run a `.txt` program anyway?

Comment: I want to run *.cmd and *.exe applications and files on remote machine and then read *.csv and *.txt files as output. After connecting to remote with Enter-PSSession then Invoke-Item "C:\Test.cmd". It dosent give any error on local machine but nothing happens on remote machine which i expect to open the text file or run the *.cmd file.

Comment: [*.azure.com]: PS C:\> Invoke-Item "C:\new_file.txt"
[*.azure.com]: PS C:\> Invoke-Item "C:\Test.cmd"
Ps: Get-Process or dir commands work very well

Comment: @Amir Do you mean you want to run the new_file.txt via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, we **can't** use `invoke-item` to open file in powershell remote session.
When we run `Invoke-Item "c:\test1.txt"`, we can't open this txt file in powershell session(**no interaction**), but this process run in background, we can use `gps` to get it, like this:
[image]

According to your description, we can run `.cmd` in Powershell remote session, like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 40.71.248.64 -Credential jason
[40.71.248.64]: PS C:\Users\jason\Documents> cd c:\
[40.71.248.64]: PS C:\> .\test.cmd

C:\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : jason
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : ym3volvuiu2uvkfm320g2dyokd.bx.internal.cloudapp.net

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ym3volvuiu2uvkfm320g2dyokd.bx.internal.cloudapp.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0D-3A-19-04-EA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9c7d:4c97:bcfc:2914%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 28, 2017 12:12:27 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, August 4, 2153 2:19:12 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.63.129.16
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301993274
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-E4-AC-C2-00-0D-3A-19-04-EA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.63.129.16
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I did the same and it works for ipconfig but it dosnet work for *.exe and my powershell running script without finishing it and i need to kiil the Ps. I also tried with *azure.com]: PS C:\windows\system32> .\calc.exe to test but same result. In my *.cmd file i have  [ start C:\*.exe "C:\*.lisp" "C:\*.LISP"]. If i use Invoke-item on powershell on the remote computer manually it runs the *.cmd and also *.exe

Comment: Like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item

Comment: @Amir In PowerShell remote session, we can't open files which have UI, for example, we cann't open calc.exe, calc will open another windows in VM, but can not open new windows in powershell remote session. powershell remote session can't open program which need UI.

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFT , Then how can i run(command to run) an *.exe on remote VM by send order from host machine?

Comment: @Amir we can use `Invoke-Command` to send argument to your .exe, but we should make sure your .exe will accept this argument. more information, please refer to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#example-11-run-a-script-on-all-the-computers-listed-in-a-text-file

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFT, Should this one work, right?            PS C:\> Invoke-command -Session $s -scriptblock {c:\windows\system32\calc.exe}     It doesn't do anything on remote machine. I need that calculator opens on remote machine

Comment: @Amir calc.exe can not accept any arguments, for test, we can use c:\windows\system32\ping.exe to test it, like this `Invoke-Command -Credential usename -ComputerName servername -Scri
ptBlock {c:\windows\system32\ping.exe www.google.com -n 2 > c:\test\ping.txt}`

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFT, Thanks, Ping works very well but how do i know which exe files are working and which of them are not like Calc? Is there any way to run something like calculator on remote machine? except Remote desktop

Comment: @Amir Just run powershell command like `ping /?` if there are some options means this exe can be run in remote vm via powershell. As far as I know, we can't run software with UI in powershell session, if we want to use UI, we should use remote desktop, not command line.

Comment: Should i use PSExec?

Comment: @Amir I think PSExec can't run remote UI.

Comment: @Amir Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFT , Thanks for your help, i couldn't run UI with power-shell remoting, i need to try other ways then